# How can I change the following array to 3-dimensions to pass it to tensorflow?

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, multidimensional-array

I'd like to train neural network on TensorFlow with an array that has 3000 rows, 3 columns, and 100 values per.

I have the following array imported:

[Array Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cntuf.png)

How do I convert this into a proper 3D array that is recognized? Thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Pandas, this looks like a job for a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html), which you can convert this into by making each row a dataframe and concatenating.

```
#~ Example data
D = pd.DataFrame([[ ['a','b','c','d'] for i in range(5) ] for i in range(5)])

#                  0             1             2             3             4
#    0  [a, b, c, d]  [a, b, c, d]  [a, b, c, d]  [a, b, c, d]  [a, b, c, d]
#    1  [a, b, c, d]  [a, b, c, d]  [a, b, c, d]  [a, b, c, d]  [a, b, c, d]
#    2  [a, b, c, d]  [a, b, c, d]  [a, b, c, d]  [a, b, c, d]  [a, b, c, d]
#    3  [a, b, c, d]  [a, b, c, d]  [a, b, c, d]  [a, b, c, d]  [a, b, c, d]
#    4  [a, b, c, d]  [a, b, c, d]  [a, b, c, d]  [a, b, c, d]  [a, b, c, d]

#~ Convert to MultiIndex
newDf = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(D.iloc[i].to_dict()).stack() for i in range(len(D))],axis=1)

#~         0  1  2  3  4
#~    0 0  a  a  a  a  a
#~      1  a  a  a  a  a
#~      2  a  a  a  a  a
#~      3  a  a  a  a  a
#~      4  a  a  a  a  a
#~    1 0  b  b  b  b  b
#~      1  b  b  b  b  b
#~      2  b  b  b  b  b
#~      3  b  b  b  b  b
#~      4  b  b  b  b  b
```

The conversion is looping through each row, and turning it into a dataframe in which the lists are columns, then stacking those into a 300,000 row Series, then combining them each into the original columns. If you'd rather have 3000 rows and 300 columns, just take `newDf.unstack(0)`.

This may also be a job for the [xarray package](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/), which is purpose-built for this kind of higher-dimensional dataset.

Comment: Hi Elliot! Thank you for your quick response. I took your answer and just transposed (newDf.T) it to get what I wanted. Thank you again!